# Multiple Clients Using Same IP

Tags: network-programming, udp

I'm having trouble using UDP with 2 clients using the same IP - after they both logged in, one of them getting both's packets. How can I solve that?

Comment: That should not happen[tm]. The clients should be on different ports and you should thus be able to differentate between them. However, without more info on your problem, it'll be hard to answer.

Comment: Hmmm it's a game client I'm building.. The server is also my code.. I'm using SFML for server and asyncsocket for the client (iOS).. What more data? BTW, I'm sending and getting on the same port. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: "the same port" - server-side or client-side? Server-side you listen on a single port, but client-side every client that comes from the same IP will have a different port. Actually, I'm quite surprised that you somehow manage to create two clients on the same IP *and* the same port :)

Comment: I mean that I bind on the server in the same port I bind on the client side.

Comment: Clients usually don't bind on a specific port - they open any ol' port (usually by passing a "0" port to the system call). That ensures that connections (uniquely identified by {clientIP, clientPort, hostIP, hostPort} tuples) don't get mixed up, clients get a random free port.

Comment: Wait, but if I will bind to 0 in the client, how can I know what port I should send in the server side to the client? 0 also?

Comment: No, you send the port you get bound to. getsockname() can be used to grab the socket address you got assigned by the OS when binding without a specified port.

Comment: Oh, ok I will send it via TCP but that weird because you can trust UDP so the server will get the port... Thanks, anyway!

Comment: No need to do TCP. recv() has a version that allows you to pass a sockaddr pointer that gets filled in with the client info. Or you just pass it in your protocol in the first UDP packet. (and, no, you cannot trust UDP, by the way :-))

Comment: @cdegroot: please compile this conversation into an answer so OP can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: don't bind to a specific port on the conversation-initiating side of either an UDP or TCP connection. By letting the OS assign a port to you (INADDR_ANY and port 0 in the socket address structure on bind()), you can have multiple clients on the same IP.

For non-connection oriented conversations (e.g. UDP), the server still needs to know where to talk back to. To this end, check the man page for recv(), which has a version (recvfrom()) that lets you pass a pointer to a socket address structure - the address will be filled in with the client info and thus can be used immediately to send packets back. So, on the server, use:

```
ssize_t
 recvfrom(int socket, void *restrict buffer, size_t length, int flags,
     struct sockaddr *restrict address,
     socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

and you'll have the sender address in the sockaddr pointer passed.

Comment: Hmmm I don't get it.. Do I need to first send the port from the client to the server? How? This recv() - that's for the client or server? I got the main idea, I just don't know how to implomment it.

Comment: send the first packet, recv() it on the server side and you'll have the ip/port combo where you need to send back to. BTW - for anyone doing TCP/IP programming, I recommend having "TCP/IP Illustrated" by Stevens at hand (all volumes except the one that deals with the BSD kernel implementation - that's for nerds ;-))